# Handling in-ambiguous yet breaking syntax in expression parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, expression, recursive-descent

### Context

I've recently come up with an issue that I couldn't solve by myself in a parser I'm writing.

This parser is a component in a compiler I'm building and the question is in regards to the expression parsing necessary in programming language parsing.

My parser uses recursive descent to parse expressions.

### The problem

I parse expressions using normal regular language parsing rules, I've eliminated left recursion in all my rules but there is one syntactic "ambiguity" which my parser simply can't handle and it involves generics.

```
comparison → addition ( ( ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" ) addition )* ;
```

is the rule I use for parsing comparison nodes in the expression

On the other hand I decided to parse generic expressions this way:

```
generic → primary ( "<" arguments ">" ) ;
```

where

```
arguments → expression ( "," expression )* ;
```

Now because generic expressions have higher precedence as they are language constructs and not mathematical expressions, it causes a scenario where the generic parser will attempt to parse expressions when it shouldn't.

For example in `a<2` it will parse "a" as a primary element of the identifier type, immediately afterwards find the syntax for a generic type, parse that and fail as it can't find the closing tag.

What is the solution to such a scenario? Especially in languages like C++ where generics can also have expressions in them if I'm not mistaken `arr<1<2>` might be legal syntax.

Is this a special edge case or does it require a modification to the syntax definition that im not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for example in a<2 it will parse "a" as a primary element of the identifier type, immideatly afterwards find the syntax for a generic type, parse that and fail as it cant find the closing tag

This particular case could be solved with backtracking or unbounded lookahead. As you said, the parser will eventually fail when interpreting this as a generic, so when that happens, you can go back and parse it as a relational operator instead. The lookahead variant would be to look ahead when seeing a `<` to check whether the `<` is followed by comma-separated type names and a `>` and only go into the generic rule if that is the case.

However that approach no longer works if both interpretations are syntactically valid (meaning the syntax actually is ambiguous). One example of that would be `x<y>z`, which could either be a declaration of a variable `z` of type `x<y>` or two comparisons. This example is somewhat unproblematic since the latter meaning is almost never the intended one, so it's okay to always interpret it as the former (this happens in C# for example).

Now if we allow expressions, it becomes more complicated. For `x<y>z` it's easy enough to say that this should never be interpreted as two comparison as it makes no sense to compare the result of a comparison with something else (in many languages using relational operators on Booleans is a type error anyway). But for something like `a<b<c>()` there are two interpretations that might both be valid: Either `a` is a generic function called with the generic argument `b<c` or `b` is a generic function with the generic argument `c` (and `a` is compared to the result of calling that function). At this point it is no longer possible to resolve that ambiguity with syntactic rules alone:

In order to support this, you'll need to either check whether the given `primary` refers to a generic function and make different parsing decisions based on that or have your parser generate multiple trees in case of ambiguities and then select the correct one in a later phase. The former option means that your parser needs to keep track of which generic functions are currently defined (and in scope) and then only go into the generic rule if the given `primary` is the name of one of those functions. Note that this becomes a lot more complicated if you allow functions to be defined after they are used.

So in summary supporting expressions as generic arguments requires you to keep track of which functions are in scope while parsing and use that information to make your parsing decisions (meaning your parser is context sensitive) or generate multiple possible ASTs. Without expressions you can keep it context free and unambiguous, but will require backtracking or arbitrary lookahead (meaning it's `LL(*)`).

Since neither of those are ideal, some languages change the syntax for calling generic functions with explicit type parameters to make it LL(1). For example:

- Java puts the generic argument list of a method before the method name, i.e. `obj.<T>foo()` instead of `obj.foo<T>()`.
- Rust requires `::` before the generic argument list: `foo::<T>()` instead of `foo<T>()`.
- Scala uses square brackets for generics and for nothing else (array subscripts use parentheses): `foo[T]()` instead of `foo<T>()`.